# Disable "speak text" in Okular

Tags: linux, kde, pdf, okular, text-to-speech

I have personally no need for this feature and have never activated it except by error.

[image]

Sometimes I click that instead of copy and that unpleasing voice starts without any obvious way to make it stop. (I know I can add a button or shortcut, but I prefer to save my memory as well as toolbar space for features that I need and use.)

Under *Configure Okular - Accessibility* there is an option to select the voice but there is none to disable it.

[image]

Is it possible to de-activate this feature?

Comment: Maybe mute Okular in Pulseaudio? I think you can do that from e.g. pavucontrol (Gnome's Volume Control application) while Okular is producing sound.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - I know I can stop the voice once started ( `while okular is producing sound`; I could mute the system anyway etc; better, as already said and dismissed in the question, I could add buttons and shortcuts to stop the voice ): but I want it *not to start in the first place*.

Comment: My point is that this would be a one-and-for-all thing: at least on a Gnome system, the per-application volume is persistent.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - The situation is different in various KDE/distros/versions. InKubuntu 20.04 the application that is playing while Okular is producing sound is QtPulseAudio, and the mute option in Plasma audio settings is **not** persistent. — I have found a solution to disable text-to-speech altogether in Kubuntu 20.04 and posted that as answer; but that solution doesn't work in Plasma 5.23 on KaOS Linux, for example. Luckily,  the setting to mute Okular voice **is** persistent on KaOS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is distro-specific.

The `flite` voice is used in Kubuntu 20.04. There, uninstalling `qtspeech5-flite-plugin` removes the voice in Okular altogether.

[image]

(`libflite1` cannot be removed because is needed by many other packages, but `qtspeech5-flite-plugin` can be removed alone in Kubuntu 20.04)

But in other distributions things are different. For example, in KaOS (with more recent Plasma), the speech engine is `speechd`. There, the packages associated with speech cannot be removed as they are depended upon by too many others. (As a workaround, the Okular voice can be muted in audio settings and that option – unlike in Kubuntu LTS – is persistent after logout, as suggested in a comment by @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' in comments.)

Comment: Yup, annoying, isn't it. It's lazy programming, that just links anything and everything that _may_ be useful, instead of going down the `dlopen` route.